# Authorization via WKWebView. Could I have troubles on AppStore review?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, appstore-approval, review

I do authorization via WKWebView. My app native but authorization via WKWebView, back-end  open my app reference and send token. I catch token in my app and user use native app as 
logged in. Is it legal? Could I have reject from AppStore review team? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow.

I believe you're asking if Apple allows the app to authenticate via Web Views. If that's so, yes, they do allow that. They have documentation that explains how to do: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/device_assignment/authenticating_through_web_views

There's also several existing threads on this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios%2bauthentication%2bwebview?tab=Votes